# Laravel - how to update whole collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to make a notification system with laravel. My idea was to get data and update instantly the "is_delivered" flag.

This is the code:

```
Model: 

public function scopeGetForView($query)
{
    $query->orderBy('created_at','DESC');

    $return = $query->get();

    if($return->count() > 0) {
        $query->update(array("is_delivered" => 1));
    }

    return $return;
}

Controller: 

$notifications = Auth::user()->notifications()->limit(10)->offset(10)->getForView();
```

Well, this would work fine without the offset because MySQL does only support limit (without offset) when updating.

But how can I update the whole collection without looping through it? Looping with instant updating would lead to many queries. The other way I can think of would be to create an array with IDs and update them with whereIn(). Is this the only way doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run an update on the whole collection:

```
DB::table('table_name')->whereIn('id', $collection->modelKeys())->update(['is_delivered' => 1]);
```

Comment: Nice! Haven't heard about the modelKeys-method. Will try it later on. Thanks!